# Read csv columns based on value in first column of any row using tinycsvparser

Tags: c#, csv, file-processing

http://bytefish.github.io/TinyCsvParser/sections/quickstart.html

how can we identify on the basis of value in first column to run the mapper of any specific class.
Like if value in first column is "Person" then it should be mapped with class A.
and if value is "Marks" then it should be mapped with class B

For Code - http://pastebin.com/JSiwF5hy

Two issues here-
1. Suppose if we get data in csv like :
P,Jack,Australia,a@a.com;
C,abc Pvt, Australia

Data is of Person or Company based on value in 1st column like P and C.
How to implement this without loading the file again.

2. As in the class structure, emailAddress comes under ContactDetails class. How to implement this functionality.

Comment: Please show us some code you have tried so far.

Comment: @MukulVarshney-Please have a look.